# Sql Server 2012 Stored procedure query with where clause is null or input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure that uses a an input parameter in the where clause.  The parameter will either be text or null.

I.e. suppose I have a table [tbl]

```
Status val
NULL   158
Acc    155
Acc    152
Null   24
Rej    34
```

In SQL server the null values can be found by using

```
WHERE Status is NULL
```

I also want the stored procedure to be able to handle a case when the parameter equals a specific value.

```
WHERE Status = @parameter
```

How do I combine both of these cases?  I want something like this.

```
CREATE PROC test @parameter VARCHAR(10) = ''

SELECT *
FROM [tbl]

IF (@parameter is NULL OR @parameter = '') THEN WHERE STATUS is Null
ELSE WHERE STATUS = @parameter
```

Comment: from your question it seems like you only want NULL rows to be fetched when `@parameter` is NULL or '', but your accepted answer **always** returns the NULL rows.

Comment: You are right.  I just realized that, i will give you credit for correctly answering the qeustion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE (ISNULL(@parameter,'') = '' AND Status IS NULL)
   OR Status = @parameter
```

The top half can only ever evaluate to true if `@Status` isn't `NULL`. Otherwise it falls back to the bottom half.

`ISNULL(@Status,'') = ''` is just the same as saying `@Status IS NULL OR @Status = ''`, and if that's the case then it matches rows where `Status IS NULL`.

Looking at your pseudocode, you were pretty much there (things I added are in bold):

> <s>`IF`</s>**(** (`@parameter is NULL OR @parameter = ''`)<s>`THEN WHERE`</s>**`AND`**`STATUS is Null`**)**
>   <s>`ELSE WHERE`</s> **`OR`** `STATUS = @parameter`

---

Just realised this might be better:

```
WHERE ISNULL(@parameter, '') = ISNULL(Status, '')
```

It will work the same, but I'm not sure if the `ISNULL(Status, '')` will stop indexes from being used, so it'd be worth checking the execution plan.

Comment: is there any way to speed up this process? it's running a little slow

Comment: The where clause itself isn't likely to cause problems, more likely you need an appropriate index that would include the Status column. Hard to advise without seeing the table + query - but a question like that *might*  be better suited to http://dba.stackexchange.com - it would likely be perfectly on topic here on SO too, but the better answers might be on dba.

Answer (score 1):

Just include both the condition in your `WHERE` clause such that it will fetch rows where `status having null's` or `status having specific value`

```
WHERE Status is NULL
OR Status = @parameter
```